# Why does submit_tag generate HTML with the name="commit" property?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, actionview

As per the [rails docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/submit_tag), using the `submit_tag` helper will generate something like

```
submit_tag
# => <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Save changes" />
```

It includes the property `name="commit"`

- Why does this get included? Is it some sort of standard? Trying to understand what "commit" means in this context
- I noticed it gets included in the `params` inside the controller after hitting submit. Was this changed recently? I thought only url params and POST/PUT data get included?

  @params

  => {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"4q3u+mfMi57YbchTAzaCI7WHmzfZJrLbTZ17aVwfq9uw8aMU1B3PBR13qfipgN6lbRoi0dywFU9i1AbJ0GP7UA==", "email"=>"foo@example.co", "password"=>"(REDACTED)", "dest"=>"", "commit"=>"Log in", "controller"=>"sessions", "action"=>"log_in"}

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is just a rails thing.  HTML5 standards allow you to provide a `name=xxxx` on your own, which you can also do with rails.  In short, `name="commit"` helps in case you need to do something [like this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968740/send-parameter-to-controller-on-submit-tag-rails) and makes sure something is passed in the parameters.